# Multiple sequential launch attempts cause app to appear unresponsive in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my WP7 application, the app is unresponsive when multiple sequential launch(Launch app > menu > launch app > menu > etc...). After about 5 or 6 iterations Splashscreen just stays in place for a few seconds. What is the reason for this? Please help me.